# how to hide parent div from 2 child divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent div and 2 nested child divs. I want to hide the first child div and the parent div when the second child div doesn't contain any content.I was wondering how this could be done?

I want to hide `#portfolio` when `.portfolio-works-container` div is empty.

```
   <div id="portfolio"><!--portfolio-->
        <div id="portfolio-works"><!--portfolio-works-->
            <div class="portfolio-works-container"><!--portfolio-works-container-->


          </div><!--/portfolio-works-container-->
        </div><!--/portfolio-works-->
   </div><!--/portfoio-->
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if($.trim($('.portfolio-works-container').html()).length == 0){
         $('#portfolio').hide();         
    }
});
```

Please check this : [jsfiddle url](http://jsfiddle.net/7WpRP/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
if($('.portfolio-works-container').contents().length == 0) {
    $('#portfolio').hide()
}
```

Comment: This will not take into consideration the text nodes. Instead of children() you could use contents()

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [`:empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector. Try this:

```
if($(".portfolio-works-container").is(':empty')){
   $("#portfolio").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery (as the question is tagged):

```
if ($('.portfolio-works-container').html()=='')
    $('#portfolio').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

IN order to hide parent div you need to find the parent element using parent() function of jquery.
In below code you will check if div is empty then find parent divs and hide them

```
if( !$.trim($('.portfolio-works-container').html()) ) {
   $(this).parent().hide();
   $(this).parent().parent().hide();

}
```